# Find the person names who own all books written by author X

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select max(c),
  name 
from(
  select 
    name,
    count(*) as c 
  from(
   book join owns using (title)
  ) 
  join  person using(ssn) 
  where author='X' 
  groupby (name)
) as counts:
```

But it showing max count and first name in the table instead of corresponding name.

Here it shows output manny 14,  but it showing max value but first name in the table you can find that in below picture.

Comment: What is below picture?

Comment: Format your query into something readable.

Comment: i want to add screenshot but it is not accepcting

Comment: Give sample data and expected output

Comment: How can you `join  person using(ssn)` when the first sub-query returns columns `name` and `c` ?

Comment: book (title, author, year, price)       
person (SSN, name , sex)                 
owns (SSN, title, FK(SSN) ref person(SSN), FK(title) ref book(title)) this is my schema

Comment: output from sub query is like man 13,crash 12, scar 1,manny 14 but when i execute this query it gives me man 14 instead of manny 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this -
Instead of giving

```
select max(c), name
```

give,

```
select c, name
...
order by c desc limit 1;
```

Comment: i agree with you answer  but what i have to write if there is two max values.

Comment: One thing may be you can try here is to remove limit & add a where condition "c = max(c)". Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: This SQLFiddle will give you a hint how to implement it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d00af/1

Comment: the sqlFiddle is extremly help ful but here in my problem maxium count can you help on that one

Comment: Can you generate an SQLFiddle with the schema and sample values?